# replace <br> with <br/ > in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

The question was obviously asked many times, but I could not find any help.

I would like to replace all

```
<br>
```

to

```
<br />
```

in some nodes.

XML

```
<paragraphs>
   <paragraph><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.<br>sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.<br>sed diam voluptua.<br>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.]]>
   </paragraph>
<paragraphs>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph">
   <paragraph>
     <xsl:attribute name="type">public</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\<br\>', '\<br /\>')"/>
   </paragraph>
</xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately Saxon quits with

```
SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The value of attribute "select"    associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "select" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
```

I tried escaping with "\" but nevertheless I can''t get it right.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am afraid what you have presented as the "XML" input with `<br>` markup is not XML at all so the whole question about wanting to replace `<br>` is rather odd, considering that XSLT usually works with XML input where you can only have `<br/>` or `<br />` or `<br></br>` but not `<br>`. So unless you are using an HTML parser on some HTML input and then feed that input to XSLT I don't see how your input could be processed with XSLT at all. And in that case there is no transformation problem, you simpy need to serialize the whole tree as XML or XHTML and then you get `<br />`.

Comment: Note also that the `replace()` function works on strings, not on markup. And the way to escape the `<` character is `&lt;`, not `\<`. But that would be relevant only  if your paragraph contained escaped breaks to begin with.

Comment: you are definitely right. i forgot <![CDATA[ ]>.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <paragraph type="public">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&lt;br>', '&lt;br/>')"/>
    </paragraph>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/gWEamKU

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use, and don't need, XSLT for this. You need an error-correcting HTML parser that produces XHTML, such as [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/), which is a thin layer over Apache Xerces.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the output property to HTML that will produce `<br>` tags without the slash.

However if you set the output property to XML, the transformer will auto close empty tags, so use:

```
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
```

Comment: "*the transformer will auto close empty tags*" It will not in this case, because they are not tags.